# CqlEngine model primary_key not raising Unique Error

Tags: flask, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlengine

I am using CassandraDB in a flask project

I have created a User Model which has email as the primary_key.

```
class User(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'user'

    user_id = UUID(primary_key=True)
    email = Text(max_length=120, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Text()
    last_name = Text()
```

python code:

```
user_data = {'email': 'john@example.com', "first_name":'John', "last_name":'Doe'}
user = User(**user_data)
user.save()
```

the Above code correctly creates the user as required

```
user_data = {'email': 'john@example.com', "first_name":'Johnny', "last_name":'Daves'}
user = User(**user_data)
user.save()
```

Now the above code updates the existing User 'john doe' to 'johnny daves'. what I was expecting to get was an error raised by cqlengine stating "user with email john@example.com already exists"

Why did it not raise the error? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure out the answer, after going through the code I was able to notice that Model class has an property called `_if_not_exists = False` which if set will raise `LWTException` indicating that the object already exists in the database and you cannot create it.

```
class User(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'user'
    _if_not_exists = True  

    user_id = UUID(primary_key=True)
    email = Text(max_length=120, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Text()
    last_name = Text()
```

as shown above setting `_if_not_exists = True` in the model solved my problem :)